# Neo4J Batch Import failure with AssertionError

Tags: neo4j

I am getting a following AssertionError when I am trying to import a very large graph 10b+ nodes and relationships.  There are potential nodes that have large # of relationships, up to 10m.  When I reduce the size of data import (< 10b nodes and up to < 1m relationships on any given node), I am not running into the error.  This is a prototype and I am trying to understand whether I am hitting a limit of some sort or if anyone can provide some directions in how to go about debugging this.

I do realize that there are 34b nodes and 34b relationships limit which is not what I am running into.

This is on Windows 64 bit machine.

Thank you.

```
2015-06-15 15:53:19.501+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Error during import Requested index -2147483648, but length is 2186000000
rangeParams:
  [0, 70483559]
  [70483559, 70484353]
  [140967912, 70483361]
  [211451273, 70484569]
  [281935842, 70484114]
  [352419956, 70481036]
  [422900992, 70477816]
  [493378808, 70481928]
  [563860736, 70479956]
  [634340692, 70477857]
  [704818549, 70484071]
  [775302620, 70480142]
  [845782762, 70487626]
  [916270388, 70483085]
  [986753473, 70487203]
  [1057240676, 70486084]
  [1127726760, 70486862]
  [1198213622, 70484457]
  [1268698079, 70484821]
  [1339182900, 70484610]
  [1409667510, 70487647]
  [1480155157, 70486347]
  [1550641504, 70488383]
  [1621129887, 70485274]
  [1691615161, 70486931]
  [1762102092, 70485245]
  [1832587337, 70486573]
  [1903073910, 70482433]
  [1973556343, 70485091]
  [2044041434, 70486198]
  [2114527632, 70626133]
bucketRange:
  661273
  674489
  687702
  700955
  714149
  724039
  730444
  736836
  743243
  749615
  756022
  762420
  768829
  775192
  781600
  789228
  800643
  812047
  823462
  834870
  846279
  1058186
  1077351
  1096513
  1114991
  1125762
  1136537
  1147309
  1158082
  1168852
  8388608
bucketIndex:
  70483559
  70484353
  70483361
  70484569
  70484114
  70481036
  70477816
  70481928
  70479956
  70477857
  70484071
  70480142
  70487626
  70483085
  70487203
  70486084
  70486862
  70484457
  70484821
  70484610
  70487647
  70486347
  70488383
  70485274
  70486931
  70485245
  70486573
  70482433
  70485091
  70486198
  32956017

java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested index -2147483648, but length is 2186000000
rangeParams:
  [0, 70483559]
  [70483559, 70484353]
  [140967912, 70483361]
  [211451273, 70484569]
  [281935842, 70484114]
  [352419956, 70481036]
  [422900992, 70477816]
  [493378808, 70481928]
  [563860736, 70479956]
  [634340692, 70477857]
  [704818549, 70484071]
  [775302620, 70480142]
  [845782762, 70487626]
  [916270388, 70483085]
  [986753473, 70487203]
  [1057240676, 70486084]
  [1127726760, 70486862]
  [1198213622, 70484457]
  [1268698079, 70484821]
  [1339182900, 70484610]
  [1409667510, 70487647]
  [1480155157, 70486347]
  [1550641504, 70488383]
  [1621129887, 70485274]
  [1691615161, 70486931]
  [1762102092, 70485245]
  [1832587337, 70486573]
  [1903073910, 70482433]
  [1973556343, 70485091]
  [2044041434, 70486198]
  [2114527632, 70626133]
bucketRange:
  661273
  674489
  687702
  700955
  714149
  724039
  730444
  736836
  743243
  749615
  756022
  762420
  768829
  775192
  781600
  789228
  800643
  812047
  823462
  834870
  846279
  1058186
  1077351
  1096513
  1114991
  1125762
  1136537
  1147309
  1158082
  1168852
  8388608
bucketIndex:
  70483559
  70484353
  70483361
  70484569
  70484114
  70481036
  70477816
  70481928
  70479956
  70477857
  70484071
  70480142
  70487626
  70483085
  70487203
  70486084
  70486862
  70484457
  70484821
  70484610
  70487647
  70486347
  70488383
  70485274
  70486931
  70485245
  70486573
  70482433
  70485091
  70486198
  32956017

    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.StageExecution.stillExecuting(StageExecution.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.anyStillExecuting(ExecutionSupervisor.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.finishAwareSleep(ExecutionSupervisor.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.supervise(ExecutionSupervisor.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisors.superviseExecution(ExecutionSupervisors.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisors.superviseDynamicExecution(ExecutionSupervisors.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.executeStages(ParallelBatchImporter.java:239)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:160)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:293)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:227)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Requested index -2147483648, but length is 2186000000
rangeParams:
  [0, 70483559]
  [70483559, 70484353]
  [140967912, 70483361]
  [211451273, 70484569]
  [281935842, 70484114]
  [352419956, 70481036]
  [422900992, 70477816]
  [493378808, 70481928]
  [563860736, 70479956]
  [634340692, 70477857]
  [704818549, 70484071]
  [775302620, 70480142]
  [845782762, 70487626]
  [916270388, 70483085]
  [986753473, 70487203]
  [1057240676, 70486084]
  [1127726760, 70486862]
  [1198213622, 70484457]
  [1268698079, 70484821]
  [1339182900, 70484610]
  [1409667510, 70487647]
  [1480155157, 70486347]
  [1550641504, 70488383]
  [1621129887, 70485274]
  [1691615161, 70486931]
  [1762102092, 70485245]
  [1832587337, 70486573]
  [1903073910, 70482433]
  [1973556343, 70485091]
  [2044041434, 70486198]
  [2114527632, 70626133]
bucketRange:
  661273
  674489
  687702
  700955
  714149
  724039
  730444
  736836
  743243
  749615
  756022
  762420
  768829
  775192
  781600
  789228
  800643
  812047
  823462
  834870
  846279
  1058186
  1077351
  1096513
  1114991
  1125762
  1136537
  1147309
  1158082
  1168852
  8388608
bucketIndex:
  70483559
  70484353
  70483361
  70484569
  70484114
  70481036
  70477816
  70481928
  70479956
  70477857
  70484071
  70480142
  70487626
  70483085
  70487203
  70486084
  70486862
  70484457
  70484821
  70484610
  70487647
  70486347
  70488383
  70485274
  70486931
  70485245
  70486573
  70482433
  70485091
  70486198
  32956017

    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.sortRadix(ParallelSort.java:180)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.run(ParallelSort.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.prepare(EncodingIdMapper.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.IdMapperPreparationStep.process(IdMapperPreparationStep.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep$1.run(LonelyProcessingStep.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of neo4j are you using here? Also is it reproducible? If it is, could I get access to the source (csv) files, purely for forensics? I'm one of the main developers of the import tool.

Comment: I am using 2.2.1.  Unfortunately, I can't share the csv files as its sensitive data.  I can try to run it again and get back to you whether it consistently repros.  Does running it on version 2.2.2 make much difference?

Comment: IIRC 2.2.2 includes a fix for this, or at least a related, problem. So please try that.